# GDB Failed to find frame when using BOOST library with GCC 4.9 on OSX

Tags: boost, gdb, g++, osx-yosemite

My problem is when debugging from Eclipse a program that uses Boost (even pure header) then the GDB debugger is unable to locate frame base for the function being trace into.

Please note that except this, the program works like a charm in debug and release mode. The problem is only for debugging and inspecting source code refering to Boost.

Please not also that the problem only affects OSX Yosemit.

The issue is that I can't see the value of the local variables. Below is the message I have in the "(x)= Variables" window of Eclipse :

```
Failed to execute MI command:
-data-evaluate-expression result
Error message from debugger back end:
Could not find the frame base for "main()".
```

The code is as simple as :

```
#include <boost/regex.hpp>
#include <iostream>
int main() {
   int result = 1;
   boost::regex reExpression("[a-z]+");

   std::cout << "!!!Hello World !!!" << std::endl;
   result ++;

  cout << " Result = " << result << "\n";
  return result;
}
```

The program is compiled using the command :

```
g++ -v -o -g bin/Essai-MACOS-Debug  src/Essai.cpp -I/opt/local/include /opt/local/lib/libboost_regex-mt.a
```

If you remove the reference to Boost.Regex then everything is ok. I can inspect the value of the local variable result.

More interesting: I built a library with a single function relying on Boost, and call that function from main(). It happens that can inspect the code in main() and have the value of main's local variable but when I came inside the library's function, the one now referring to boost then again I can't see the local variables of that function.

So it seems that as soon as a source file is referring to Boost, GDB get confused.

I have installed GCC 4.9, GDB 7.7 and Boost 1.57 using MacPort on OSX Yosemit.

I've compile Boost from source with MacPort in order to use GCC instead of GCC using the command :

sudo port install -ns boost config.compiler=macport-gcc-4.9

I also tried with a version of Boost I compiled myself and I did have the same issue.

Does anyone knows about this problem ?

**EDIT:**
I've compiled and installed the last GDB version from sources (7.9) and have the same issue described here than with the 7.7.1 provided by MacPorts.